# D3: Removing Elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart that creates positive and negative bars.  I'm trying to remove the negative bars later on but for now, even after appending the bars, if I try to immediately remove the negative bars, they still appear.

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 750 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = data.length * 20 //500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width*.85])

//chart1.x =x
//chart1.y = y

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("top");

var svg = d3.select("#barchart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage; })).nice();
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

  bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(Math.min(0, +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage)); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return Math.abs(x(+d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage) - x(0)); })
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand()).style("stroke","white")

bar.selectAll(".negative").data([]).exit().remove()
```

The remove statement is the last one.  The rest of the code:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("text").text(function(d) {
        return d;
   }).attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return y(d.name)+ y.rangeBand();
        //return i * (height / data.length)+30;
   }).attr("x", function(d) {
         return x(0) //x(Math.min(0, +d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage));
   }).text(function(d) {
        //return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2;
        return d.name + " " + d.netdonations_over_population_to_gdppercap_percentage;
        }).style("font-size","14px").attr("dx", 3).attr("dy", "-0.45em")


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("line")
      .attr("x1", x(0))
      .attr("x2", x(0))
      .attr("y2", height);
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

try switching your selectAll statement to:

```
svg.selectAll("rect.negative").remove()
```

This should select the tags `rect` with class `negative`although I'm not 100% sure it will find it because the `attr` `class` is written as `bar negative`. If it doesn't work I might try changing your `class` attribute to something like `negative bar` or just `negative`.

Sorry if this doesn't help!

Comment: Thanks.  This also worked: svg.selectAll(".bar.negative").data([]).exit().remove()

Comment: Do you actually need an empty data selection? Can't you just remove them outright? svg.selectAll("rect.negative").remove()